# Urn problem, probability of drawing 2 balls of the same color

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

Here is my question:

Having an urn with $\frac{n}{2}$ black balls and $\frac{n}{2}$ red balls. What is the probability when drawing two balls at the same time to draw two balls of the same color if you repeatedly draw and put one ball back until only two balls are left in the urn.

$Pr[$Drawing only pairs of the same color$] = ? $

This problem originates from a graph problem. Having two graphs A and B each with $|V|= \frac{n}{2}$ vertices. Picking two vertices from the combined vertices of A and B uniformly at random and merging them into one vertice (which is then again in the set as type A or B or AB). Doing this until there are only two vertices left. What is the probability to always pick two vertices from A or two vertices from B.

For the first draw the probability is, I believe, $2∗\frac{1}{2}*\frac{\frac{n}{2}-1}{n−1} $but then the possible combinations grow exponentially large and I don't know how to combine them in a closed form.

Comment: Just to be sure, you want the probability that every draw comprises two balls of the same color?

Comment: yes, I need to show that this propability is exponentially small (dependent on n)

Comment: What have you done so far?  How far have you gotten?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: You ought to put your thoughts on the problem into the body of the question.  Also, include the graph problem you are modeling.  With no more context than you have given, you are liable have the question closed.  Many people browsing the question will vote to close without reading the comments, so be sure to edit the question.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you need an exact expression for the probability or just to show that it is exponentially small as a function of $n$?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to find an expression for the probability, or even an approach to it, so I'm trying to prove that the probability is exponentially small as a function of $n$.  I think I have the right idea, but I can't quite dispose of it.  Suppose we have $r$ red balls and $b$ black balls.  Say that the red balls are in the minority if $r\le b,$ and in the majority if $r>b$ and similarly for the black balls.  The probability of choosing two balls of the same color is $${{r\choose2}+{b\choose2}\over{r+b\choose2}}\le1$$  If the red balls are in the minority, then the probability of choosing two red balls is $$ 
{{r\choose2}\over{r+b\choose2}}<=\frac12{{r\choose2}+{b\choose2}\over{r+b\choose2}}\le\frac12\cdot1=\frac12$$  It seems intuitively clear that, to fulfill the conditions in the problem,  we must choose balls in the minority at least as often as balls in the majority (with perhaps some minor adjustment) so that we can say that the probability of overall success is $\le \left(\frac12\right)^{n/2}.$  I haven't seen how to prove this formally though.  Some kind of inductive argument perhaps?

Comment: @dave4422 Please delete your prior comments, as they don't relate to my revised answer.